# Python 2.7 CSV graph time format

Tags: python-2.7, csv, numpy

I have a CSV file, one of colons value is timestamps but when I use numpy.getfromtxt it change it to string. My goal is to create a graph but with normal time format I prefer seconds only.

this is my array that I get from bellow code:

```
array([('0:00:00',), ('0:00:00.001000',), ('0:00:00.002000',),
 ('0:00:00.081000',), ('0:00:00.095000',), ('0:00:00.195000',),
 ('0:00:00.294000',), ...
```

this is my code:

```
col1 = numpy.genfromtxt("mycsv.csv",usecols=(1),delimiter=',',dtype=None, names=True)
```

The problem that I am having that format is in string but I need it in seconds (us can be ignored or not). How can I achive that?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how to change string format to seconds

Comment: please update your question.

Comment: it looks like these timestamps are `h:m:s.ms` - what is the epoch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, the best way for working with `csv` files in python is to use `pandas`.  It takes care of this for you.  I will assume the name of the time column is `time`, change it to whatever you use:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=[1])  # read time as date
>>> print(df)
   test1                    time  test2  test3
0      5 2015-08-20 00:00:00.000     10   11.7
1      5 2015-08-20 00:00:00.001     11   11.6
2      5 2015-08-20 00:00:00.002     12   11.5
3      5 2015-08-20 00:00:00.081     13   11.4
4      5 2015-08-20 00:00:00.095     14   11.3
5      5 2015-08-20 00:00:00.195     15   11.2
6      5 2015-08-20 00:00:00.294     16   11.1
>>> df['time'] -= pd.datetime.now().date()  # convert to timedelta
>>> print(df)
   test1            time  test2  test3
0      5        00:00:00     10   11.7
1      5 00:00:00.001000     11   11.6
2      5 00:00:00.002000     12   11.5
3      5 00:00:00.081000     13   11.4
4      5 00:00:00.095000     14   11.3
5      5 00:00:00.195000     15   11.2
6      5 00:00:00.294000     16   11.1
>>> df['time'] /= np.timedelta64(1,'s')  # convert to seconds
>>> print(df)    
   test1   time  test2  test3
0      5  0.000     10   11.7
1      5  0.001     11   11.6
2      5  0.002     12   11.5
3      5  0.081     13   11.4
4      5  0.095     14   11.3
5      5  0.195     15   11.2
6      5  0.294     16   11.1
```

You can work with pandas dataframes (what you have here) and series (what you would from getting a single column, such as `df['time']`) in most of the same ways as numpy arrays, including plotting.  However, if you really, really need to convert it to a numpy array, it is as easy as `arr = df['time'].values`.

Comment: This module pandas is awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) library

```
 import datetime

 for x in array:
     for y .... # it's not realy obvious what the nesting is here...
        timestamp = datetime.strptime(y, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: you know, if you asked a clear question you'd get a good answer much more quickly

Comment: try reading the numpy docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html

Comment: @scytale: Did you try this yourself?  It looks like you have the arguments to `strptime` reversed.  Also, `strptime` returns a `struct_time` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time), which does not support fractions of a second.

Comment: i was thinking of datetime. and yes, the args are reversed.

Comment: The first string in the sample is `'0:00:00'`.  With this input, your call to `strptime` will fail, because there is no decimal point.

Comment: I'm not really interested in doing all the OP's homework - I have no idea how many varations on the format they need to support - I think my example was enough. if you want to edit please do

Answer (score 1):

You can use a converter for the timestamp field.

For example, suppose `times.dat` contains:

```
time
0:00:00
0:00:00.001000
0:00:00.002000
0:00:00.081000
0:00:00.095000
0:00:00.195000
0:00:00.294000
```

Define a converter that converts a timestamp string into the number of seconds as a floating point value:

```
In [5]: def convert_timestamp(s):
   ...:     h, m, s = [float(w) for w in s.split(':')]
   ...:     return h*3600 + m*60 + s
   ...:
```

Then use the converter in `genfromtxt`:

```
In [21]: genfromtxt('times.dat', skiprows=1, converters={0: convert_timestamp})
Out[21]: array([ 0.   ,  0.001,  0.002,  0.081,  0.095,  0.195,  0.294])
```